# Bash: while terminate early when reading from file

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to run a file that contains a sequence of commands/scripts to run with arguments, like:

```
ls /etc/
cat /etc/hosts/
script.sh some parameters 
...
```

This seems to work fine but in some cases the while loop will end prematurely. This seems to be the case only when the scripts it is executing contains SSH/SCP at the end. The code to read the file:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    # Cut command and parameters
    IFS=', ' read -a parameters <<< "$line"
    cmd="${parameters[0]}"
    unset parameters[0]
    runScriptAndCheckError "$cmd" "${parameters[@]}"
done < "$SCRIPT_FILENAME"
```

When using set -x:

```
+ checkError 0 'ERROR: script.sh failed'
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ IFS=
+ read -r line
```

It looks like there is no more input although there is still lines in the file. If I comment out runScriptAndCheckError "$cmd" "${parameters[@]}" then it does print a lot more lines.

I am not sure what is wrong with this code. I'd be really helpful if someone could please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `runScriptAndCheckError` also reads from standard input, it will read lines from `$SCRIPT_FILENAME`. Have the `read` command in the `while` loop use a different file descriptor:

```
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
  ...
done 3< "$SCRIPT_FILENAME"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Stealing Input

The key is as @chepner states, that the statements inside:

```
read line; do
   <command>
done
```

Will interfere with the loop if they attempt to read from stdin.

If you don't want your script reading from stdin, prevent it from doing so as follows:

```
read line; do
   cmd < /dev/null
done
```

Now your read loop will not be missing any input.